# Installing OS on SSD but keeping already exsisting files from HDD without formatting drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, operating-systems, desktop

I just bought an SSD drive today for my custom built desktop computer. I already have windows 10 and all the drivers and programs and updates install to my current HDD. I now want to take windows 10 and install it on the SSD. I want to be able to get rid of windows 10 on my current HDD but keep all the content i have installed it already. Is there any special methods I must do in order to keep everything proper and working? How can I do this. It would be great if there is a guide that I can refer to. I am having difficulties trying to find my exact answer as they all seem opposite of what I want to do.

Comment: Just clone the hdd to the SSD?

Comment: @Ramhound wouldn't that also clone Windows? I think OP wants to have it so that Windows is on the new SSD, but installed programs stay on the HDD.

Answer (score -1):

One method

1. Ensure SSD is installed in the system, but no need to format.
2. Clean up your windows disk, removing caches, temp files, old service packs, and any data that you don't want on your SSD. [Treesize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) can help with this.
3. Install [Macrium Reflect free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) on  your current drive.
4. Create a boot USB drive
5. Boot from USB, create an image of Windows 10.
6. Write disk image to the SSD.
7. Boot using the SSD. Do anything else you like, such as deleting the Windows folder.